# SQL Server -- search through stored procedures?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am working on a SQL Server database that has hundreds of stored procedures.  I would like to be able to search through the *text* of the queries (*NOT* the results) to find a list of stored procedures that already exist.  For example, if I need to create a new stored procedure, I might want to search through all the existing stored procedures that deal with table MyTable to see if a similar (or even identical) stored procedure already exists.  Is there a way to search for the string "MyTable" and end up with a list of all the stored procedures that include "MyTable"?

Comment: oops!  Going against my usual policy, I didn't search for the answer first... figures that _this time_ it exists.  Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the SSMS add-in [ObjectFinder](http://ssmsaddins.codeplex.com/) to perform a full-text search over Stored Procedures.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[Search_Stored_Procedure_Code]
(
    @SearchStr  varchar(100),
    @RowsReturned   int = NULL  OUT
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SELECT  DISTINCT USER_NAME(o.uid) + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(c.id) AS 'Object name',
        CASE 
            WHEN OBJECTPROPERTY(c.id, 'IsReplProc') = 1 
                THEN 'Replication stored procedure'
            WHEN OBJECTPROPERTY(c.id, 'IsExtendedProc') = 1 
                THEN 'Extended stored procedure'                
            WHEN OBJECTPROPERTY(c.id, 'IsProcedure') = 1 
                THEN 'Stored Procedure' 
            WHEN OBJECTPROPERTY(c.id, 'IsTrigger') = 1 
                THEN 'Trigger' 
            WHEN OBJECTPROPERTY(c.id, 'IsTableFunction') = 1 
                THEN 'Table-valued function' 
            WHEN OBJECTPROPERTY(c.id, 'IsScalarFunction') = 1 
                THEN 'Scalar-valued function'
            WHEN OBJECTPROPERTY(c.id, 'IsInlineFunction') = 1 
                THEN 'Inline function'  
        END AS 'Object type',
        'EXEC sp_helptext ''' + USER_NAME(o.uid) + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(c.id) + '''' AS 'Run this command to see the object text'
    FROM    syscomments c
        INNER JOIN
        sysobjects o
        ON c.id = o.id
    WHERE   c.text LIKE '%' + @SearchStr + '%'  AND
        encrypted = 0               AND
        (
        OBJECTPROPERTY(c.id, 'IsReplProc') = 1      OR
        OBJECTPROPERTY(c.id, 'IsExtendedProc') = 1  OR
        OBJECTPROPERTY(c.id, 'IsProcedure') = 1     OR
        OBJECTPROPERTY(c.id, 'IsTrigger') = 1       OR
        OBJECTPROPERTY(c.id, 'IsTableFunction') = 1 OR
        OBJECTPROPERTY(c.id, 'IsScalarFunction') = 1    OR
        OBJECTPROPERTY(c.id, 'IsInlineFunction') = 1    
        )

    ORDER BY    'Object type', 'Object name'

    SET @RowsReturned = @@ROWCOUNT
END
```

To search the database for the keyword 'FlowerOrders' and also find the number of hits:

```
DECLARE @Hits int
EXEC Search_Stored_Procedure_Code 'FlowerOrders', @Hits OUT
SELECT 'Found ' + LTRIM(STR(@Hits)) + ' object(s) containing this keyword' AS Result
```

Comment: Don't use `syscomments` for this task on SQL Server 2005+. It can fail on definitions > 4000 characters

Comment: Why not use  `o.type`  or `o.xtype` ?

Answer (score 1):

[Redgate](http://www.red-gate.com) makes a set of tools that includes a search facility. You may find it useful.